# how to reduce number of similar queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a very basic analytics feature for my Rails app. I want to provide statistics that tell users how many visitors have viewed their profile, and then also break those down according to the particular role (I'm using 'rolify' in my app) each visitor has.

In the show action of the Users controller, I do this

```
@profileviews = Profileview.where(:user_id => @user.id)
@profileviewsbysomerole = Profileview.where({:user_id => @user.id, :viewer_role => 'someRole'})
@profileviewsbysomeotherrole = Profileview.where({:user_id => @user.id, :viewer_role => 'someOtherRole'})
```

and then in the show action, I'd do

```
Your profile has been viewed <%= @profileviews.size %> times.
Your profile has been viewed by users with a particular role <%= @profileviewsbysomerole.size %> times.
Your profile has been viewed by users with some other role <%= @profileviewsbysomeotherrole.size %> times.
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do without making three separate queries, or is this the best way (in terms of not degrading performance) to obtain these stats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of performance I think it is OK. The other option would be to query for all the objects and then filter in memory, but I don't think this is a good idea. It's best to let the database do what it does best.

One thing that comes to mind -- you could use a single query and [group_by](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group) in order to avoid making the second and third calls, but that's relevant if you're looking to get some aggregated data.

In terms of coding style, you could define scopes for the different queries and use them from the view, but it might be an overkill.

Comment: Agreed, I would define some scopes for those queries but I wouldn't use them from the views. It'd just make the code look cleaner

Comment: Thanks for the information. Would you mind showing me how the group_by could avoid the second and third calls? I understand how it be used generally, but I don't see how it could avoid the calls.

Comment: For example, if you want to count the views for each role you can do something like: Profileviews.select("count(profileviews.id) as num_views, viewer_role as role").group("role")

Comment: Thanks for showing me this. I'll play around with it and consider using it. I find all of the answers helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself using these things together a lot, it might be nice to bundle them up together something like this:

```
# in user model
def profile_view_hash(*roles)
  views = { 'all' => Profileview.where(:user_id => id).all }
  roles.each do |role|
    views.merge!({
      role => Profileview.where(:user_id => id, :viewer_role => role).all
    })
  end
  views
end
```

This should allow you to use it like this:

```
# in controller
@profile_views = @user.profile_view_hash('someRole','someOtherRole')

# in view
<%= @profile_views['all'] %>
<%= @profile_views['someRole'] %>
<%= @profile_views['someOtherRole'] %>
```

By the way, in your example, you are only showing the output of .size. If that's all you need, you should be using `count` instead of `all`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is great. Regarding your last comment, are you saying I should do this in my controller if all I need is the size (which might be in some cases, and not in others): @profileviewsbysomerole = Profileview.where({:user_id => user.id, :viewer_role => 'somerole'}).count

Comment: by adding the count at the end of the query, does it prevent Rails from retrieving all before counting?

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil Yes, using .count will transform the SQL query to `select count(*) from profile_views where yadda yadda..`, which will be way faster, but won't have any data.

Comment: Thanks for showing me this. I'll play around with it and consider using it.

Answer (score 1):

I would leave them all out of the controller, and make the view like this:

```
Your profile has been viewed <%= @user.profileviews.size %> times.
Your profile has been viewed by users with a particular role <%= @user.profileviews.select { |profile_view| profile_view.viewer_role == 'someRole' }.size %> times.
Your profile has been viewed by users with some other role <%= @user.profileviews.select { |profile_view| profile_view.viewer_role == 'someOtherRole' }.size %> times.
```

You could take this even further by moving this logic to the `Profileview`, maybe like:

```
def views_for_role( role )
  select { |profile_view| profile_view.viewer_role == role }.size
end
```

and delegating it in the `User`, maybe like:

```
delegate :views_for_role, :to => :profileview
```

Which would make your view look like this:

```
Your profile has been viewed <%= @user.profileviews.size %> times.
Your profile has been viewed by users with a particular role <%= @user.views_for_role 'someRole' %> times.
Your profile has been viewed by users with some other role <%= @user.views_for_role 'someOtherRole' %> times.
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me this. I'll play around with it and consider using it.